# How to make visuals appear with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi im a beginner in javascript/jquery. I am making an application that takes batteries (drawn in CSS) and allows the user to connect the + and - terminals by clicking and then displays an overall voltage and Amp hour output based on how the batteries are wired.

How would I allow the user to click the positive or negative squares (which are just div tags within the battery class) and then relay to javascript that the user has clicked certain boxes, THEN somehow a wire (just a line) would appear between where the user clicked. I really don't know how I would go about coding this. THANKS

```
HTML: 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="batterypagestylesheet.css">


    <script>

    </script>
</head>
</body>
    <div id="batterysection">
        <div id="pterminal">+ terminal</div>
        <div id="nterminal">- terminal</div>


    </div>
    <div class="battery">
        <div id="pos">+</div>
        <div id="neg">-</div>
    </div>
    <div class="battery2">
        <div id="pos">+</div>
        <div id="neg">-</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


CSS:

    #batterysection{
background-color:purple;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1100px;
height:800px;
}

#pterminal{
position:absolute;
left:500px;
top:50px;
width:200px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
color:white;
text-align:center;
font-size:40px;
}
#nterminal{
position:absolute;
left:700px;
top:50px;
width:200px;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
font-size:40px;
}

.battery{
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:600px;
width:100px;
height:75px;
background-color:grey;
border:solid 2px;
}
.battery2{
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:700px;
width:100px;
height:75px;
background-color:grey;
border:solid 2px;
}

#pos{
position:relative;
height:25px;
width:25px;
background-color:red;
color:white;
margin-left:40px;
text-align:center;
}
#neg{
position:relative;
height:25px;
width:25px;
background-color:black;
color:white;
margin-left:40px;
top:20px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a very basic

```
$('#pterminal').click(function() {
    // pterminal clicked
});
```

you have a click-event handler with jQuery.

Drawing a line sounds something you would do on a HTML5 canvas-element these days. Seeing you're a beginner, you might invest some time in a course like http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-SWM11/0/1.

Also watch out with what is an *id* and what a *class*. Id's (#) are unique, there is only one - Classes (.) are a bit like tags: use them when you have similar stuff. Thus, it makes more sense to make #battery1 and #battery2 id's and .pos and .neg classes.

Comment: Note the question has no jQuery tag